# Missing space between "Results found" or "Results for <keyword>" and "Search options"

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, whitespace

When conducting a search where the results page has "Results found" and "Search options" next to each other (that is, searches that don't contain tags but use a search operator, [example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq)), a space is missing:

[image: no space between "Results found" and "Search options"]

> Results foundSearch options <options>

If a keyword is added, the lack of space appears after the keyword:

[image: no space between "dog" and "Search options"]

> Results for <keyword>Search options <options>

I don't remember this happening before but lack any pictures to prove so.

Comment: It has been like this for a while. I've seen it a few times before but I didn't pay much attention to it. Thought `foundSearch` was some kind of a param name or something. LOL. I feel stupid now.

Comment: @41686d6564 it’s not a bug it’s a feature =)